# Python Flask: What is requesting a page to trigger a 404 error several times a second?

Tags: python, flask, iis

This is sitting on an internal development server with no access from the outside world

In my logs I have

```
2022-06-20 11:25:21,376 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,392 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,548 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,673 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,736 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,751 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,830 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2022-06-20 11:25:21,892 - ERROR - __init__.py - handle_error_404 - 64 - 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

This is in a Python Flask installation on IIS. The error handling is done thus:

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'logs', 'error_log.log'), maxBytes=102400, backupCount=10)
logging_format = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)s - %(message)s')
    
handler.setFormatter(logging_format)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    
def handle_error_404(error):
    """
    404
    """
    app.logger.error(error)
    flash(f'Server says: {error}', 'error')
    return render_template('404.jinja2', layout = 'container')
    
def handle_error_400(error):
    """
    400
    """
    app.logger.error(error)
    flash(f'Server says: {error}', 'error')
    return render_template('400.jinja2', layout = 'container')
    
def handle_error_500(error):
    """
    500
    """
    app.logger.error(error)
    flash(f'Server says: {error}', 'error')
    return render_template('500.jinja2', selected_menu_item=None)
    
app.errorhandler(400)(handle_error_400)
app.errorhandler(404)(handle_error_404)
app.errorhandler(500)(handle_error_500)
```

How do I find out what's calling the page and what page is it calling?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I added the below

```
@app.before_request
    def before():
        app.logger.debug(request.url)
        app.logger.debug(request.remote_addr)
```

I now get the following:

```
/Discovery/HTTPsvc/IISXferWanServer.DLL
```

Comment: It's probably a bot.

Comment: I need to add some context. It's an internal development server that only me and a colleague have access to but I can't be sure whether he has added a link somewhere

Comment: I think you need to use failed request tracing to check those requests so that you can get more error message.